# Determining Number of Groups Returned From Regex Search in Python

Tags: python, regex, match

I'm performing a regex search in python like the one below:

```
import re
regexSearch = re.search(r'FTP-exception-sources-\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', line, re.M|re.I )
if regexSearch:
        outputFile2.write(str(lineCounter) + " , " + regexSearch.group(0) + "\n")
```

How can I determine the number of `groups` that get returned from the regex search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`regexSearch.groups()` is all of the groups. `len(regexSearch.groups())` gets the count.
In your case there will always be 0 groups as your regex does not contain groups (`group(0)` is the whole match and not really a group)

Comment: `groups()` does not contain the whole match, therefore it will return an empty tuple if the expression doesn't contain any groups.

Comment: How could I go about making groups with my regex search?

Comment: Use parenthesis (`()`) like so `regex regex (group1)more (.*group2)` see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: could I use the `findall` function to make groups?

Comment: `findall()` doesn't have anything to do with groups. It allows you to find all matches. If you wish you can use it to find all matches.